# How to read the value from a Dictionary via .TryGetValue() if the value is a tuple?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary of type

```
Dictionary<int, (float, float)>
```

when trying to read the value from it I can't use this way

```
if (myDict.TryGetValue(1, out (float tupleItem1, float tupleItem2))) { /* ... */ }
```

because then I get compile errors

[image]

The way it works is

```
if (myDict.TryGetValue(1, out (float, float) theTuple)) { /* ... */ }
```

Is there a way I can directly initialize the variables like so?

```
if (!myDict.TryGetValue(1, out (float tupleItem1, float tupleItem2)))
{
    /* handle if not found */
    tupleItem1 = 111;
    tupleItem2 = -12345;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't deconstruct directly in an `out` parameter yet unfortunately, see [this proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/611).

You'll have to deconstruct it yourself:

```
if (!myDict.TryGetValue(1, out var result))
{
    result = (111, -12345);
}
```

---

You can improve this situation slightly with an extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue? TryGetValue<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key) where TValue : struct
    {
        return dict.TryGetValue(key, out var result) ? result : null;
    }
}
```

This lets you write:

```
if (myDict.TryGetValue(1) is not (float tupleItem1, float tupleItem2))
{
    tupleItem1 = 111;
    tupleItem2 = -12345;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you could write a simple little extension method to make it more readable:

```
public static class DictionaryExt
{
    public static TValue TryGetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, Func<TValue> getDefault)
    {
        return dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value) 
            ? value 
            : getDefault();
    }
}
```

Then your sample code could looks something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, (float, float)>();

var result = dict.TryGetValueOrDefault(1, () => (111, -12345));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I chose to use `Func<TValue>` rather than `TValue` for the default so that you don't have to create a default value that isn't going to be used in the case that the dictionary already contains the key.

If you want a slightly simpler syntax and you don't care that the default is created for every call regardless of whether it's actually needed you could write it like this instead:

```
public static class DictionaryExt
{
    public static TValue TryGetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        return dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value)
            ? value
            : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Which would be called like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, (float, float)>();

var result = dict.TryGetValueOrDefault(1, (111, -12345));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

You could of course include both methods in `DictionaryExt` for more flexibility.

(It's also entirely possible that the overhead of creating a `Func<TValue>` for every call is greater than creating a tuple for each call, so if you're worried about performance you should test it. In either case, you could pass in a precreated Func or Tuple to avoid the creation overhead.)